# Spring boot: Optional parameter query in Query method

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpql

I am new to Spring boot and hibernate. Here I am trying run a search based optional parameter query Where i can search by name, country etc. If I kept this field null then query should all list. But the problem is my method is returning all data ignoring my search parameter. my model class look like

```
@Entity(name="MLFM_ORDER_OWNER")
public class ModelOrderOwner {

    @Id @GenericGenerator(name = "custom_sequence", strategy = 
            "com.biziitech.mlfm.IdGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "custom_sequence")
    @Column(name="ORDER_OWNER_ID")
    private Long orderOwnerId;

    @Column(name="OWNER_NAME")
    private String ownerName;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="BUSINESS_TYPE_ID")
    private ModelBusinessType businessTypeId;

    @Column(name="SHORT_CODE")
    private String shortCode;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="OWNER_COUNTRY")
    private ModelCountry ownerCountry;
// getter setter..
```

My Repository interface looks like

```
public interface OrderOwnerRepository extends 

    JpaRepository<ModelOrderOwner,Long>{
        @Query("select a from MLFM_ORDER_OWNER a where a.businessTypeId.typeId=coalsec(:typeId,a.businessTypeId.typeId) and a.ownerCountry.countryId=coalsec(:countryId,a.ownerCountry.countryId) and a.ownerName LIKE %:name and a.shortCode LIKE %:code")
        public List <ModelOrderOwner> findOwnerDetails(@Param("typeId")Long typeId,@Param("countryId")Long countryId,@Param("name")String name,@Param("code")String code);

    }
```

And here is my method in controller

```
@RequestMapping(path="/owners/search")
     public String getAllOwner(Model model,@RequestParam("owner_name") String name,@RequestParam("shortCode") String code,

                            @RequestParam("phoneNumber") String phoneNumber,@RequestParam("countryName") Long countryId,
                            @RequestParam("businessType") Long typeId
             ) {
 model.addAttribute("ownerList",ownerRepository.findOwnerDetails(typeId, countryId, name, code));

            return "data_list";
    }
```

Can Any one help me in this regard? please?

Comment: You could try to use Specifications (requires a bit of setup)https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know how but below code is working for me:

```
@Query("select a from MLFM_ORDER_OWNER a  
where a.businessTypeId.typeId=COALESCE(:typeId,a.businessTypeId.typeId) 
and a.ownerCountry.countryId=COALESCE(:countryId,a.ownerCountry.countryId) 
and a.ownerName LIKE %:name and a.shortCode LIKE %:code")
public List <ModelOrderOwner> findOwnerDetails(
@Param("typeId")Long typeId,
@Param("countryId")Long countryId,
@Param("name")String name,
@Param("code")String code);
```

and in my controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(path="/owners/search")
public String getAllOwner(Model model,
@RequestParam("owner_name") String name,
@RequestParam("shortCode") String code,
@RequestParam("phoneNumber") String phoneNumber,
@RequestParam("countryName") Long countryId,
@RequestParam(value = "active", required = false) String active, @RequestParam("businessType") Long typeId) {
if(typeId==0)
  typeId=null;
if(countryId==0)
  countryId=null; model.addAttribute("ownerList",ownerRepository.findOwnerDetails(typeId, countryId, name, code, status));
return "data_list";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It is too late too answer, but for anyone who looks for a solution yet there is a more simple way as below:

In my case my controller was like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/order")
public class OrderController {

    private final IOrderService service;

    public OrderController(IOrderService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{username}/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<ListResponse<UserOrdersResponse>> getUserOrders(
            @RequestHeader Map<String, String> requestHeaders,
            @RequestParam(required=false) Long id,
            @RequestParam(required=false) Long flags,
            @RequestParam(required=true) Long offset,
            @RequestParam(required=true) Long length) {
        // Return successful response
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.getUserOrders(requestDTO), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have `Username` as `@PathVariable` and `length` and `offset` which are my required parameters, but I accept `id` and `flags` for filtering search result, so they are my optional parameters and are not necessary for calling the REST service.

Now in my repository layer I have just created my `@Query` as below:

```
@Query("select new com.ada.bourse.wealth.services.models.response.UserOrdersResponse(FIELDS ARE DELETED TO BECOME MORE READABLE)" +
        " from User u join Orders o on u.id = o.user.id where u.userName = :username" +
        " and (:orderId is null or o.id = :orderId) and (:flag is null or o.flags = :flag)")
Page<UserOrdersResponse> findUsersOrders(String username, Long orderId, Long flag, Pageable page);
```

And that's it, you can see that I checked my optional arguments with `(:orderId is null or o.id = :orderId)` and `(:flag is null or o.flags = :flag)` and I think it needs to be emphasized that **I checked my argument** with `is null` condition **not my columns data**, so if client send `Id` and `flags` parameters for me I will filter the Result with them otherwise I just query with `username` which was my `@PathVariable`.

Answer (score 1):

JPQL doesn't support optional parameters.
There is no easy way of doing this in JPQL. You will have to write multiple *WHERE* clauses with *OR* operator.

Refer these answers to similar questions: [Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444603/optional-parameters-with-named-query-in-hibernate) & [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50569238/set-optional-parameters-in-jpql-query)

PS: You might want to look into [Query by Example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example) for your use case. It supports handling of null parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JpaSpecificationExecutor` //`import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;`

**Step 1**: Implement `JpaSpecificationExecutor` in your JPA Repository

Ex:

```
public interface TicketRepo extends JpaRepository<Ticket, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Ticket> {
```

**Step 2** Now to fetch tickets based on optional parameters you can build Specification query using CriteriaBuilder

Ex:

```
public Specification<Ticket> getTicketQuery(Integer domainId, Calendar startDate, Calendar endDate, Integer gameId, Integer drawId) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("domainId"), domainId));
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("createdAt"), startDate));
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("createdAt"), endDate));

        if (gameId != null) {
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("gameId"), gameId));
        }

        return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    };
}
```

Step 3: Pass the Specification instance to jpaRepo.findAll(specification), it will return you the list of your entity object (Tickets here in the running example)

```
ticketRepo.findAll(specification); // Pass output of function in step 2 to findAll
```