# Java createNativeQuery: How to set parameter as an option?

Tags: java, jpa, nativequery, hibernate-native-query

I have an use-case where passing parameters is optional. Can this be somehow achieved as if I try to set parameter (Using keyName or position) and if the key or position is absent in main query it returns IllegalParameterException.

This is useful if I have a dynamic query coming into method and want's to set some default values if possible.

Say:

```
Select ............ where date = :date
```

And if we have parameter value set for key "date" that will be used.

In other cases

```
Select .............. where date = NOW()
```

Here even though we have value set for key "date", we don't need to use

Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: Try `(:date IS NULL && date=NOW()) || (date = :date)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50569238/set-optional-parameters-in-jpql-query

Comment: Thanks @Grim, this works, but still if I set parameter which is not on query it throws an error. 
Btw - how to deal with "between :abc AND :xyz" situations!

Comment: Jake, yes I missed that point. I guess this is unspecified and can cause exception on drivers on different sql-driver-implementations.